# Could you send messages from a chrome extension to a node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I recently started on a little project. I am building an extension that opens to a local webpage that is hosted on my local node.js server. I want to send a message to my node.js server to initiate a bash script on my computer. If you're wondering... the bash script is going to open Chrome with certain flags enabled/disabled.

It would go something like this: 
ChromeExtension.Sendmessage() --> Node.js server picks up message --> Node.js server initiates bashscript

Is this possible? The only thing I really came across was native messaging, but I really don't want to go down that path if it's not even possible...

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried making a http request to localhost from your extension?

Comment: I will try that @junvar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and it can be done in a simple way

```
 var xj = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xj.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/log", true);
 xj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 xj.send(JSON.stringify({ action: <your data>}));
 xj.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xj.readyState == 4) { 
     console.log(xj.responseText);
   }
 }
```